# Python Inheritance Calling Constructor Issue

Tags: python

I have the following class inheritance structure:

```
class BuffEvent(object):
    def __init__(self, buffable):
        self.buffable = buffable


class BattleEvent(BuffEvent):
    def __init__(self, battle, buffable):
        super(BuffEvent, self).__init__(buffable)
        self.battle = battle


class BattleStartEvent(BattleEvent):
    def __init__(self, battle, buffable):
        super(BattleEvent, self).__init__(battle, buffable)
```

Then im tryng to call the constructor of BattleStartEvent like this:

```
BattleStartEvent(battle, battle.attacker)
```

But i am getting the following error:

```
    super(BattleEvent, self).__init__(battle, buffable)
TypeError: __init__() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

In BattleStartEvent i have 2 parameters in the constructor so im a bit confused. What am i doing wrong here ?

Comment: Does your code need to be compatible with Python 2?

Comment: The argument to `super` should be the class itself, not its super class. Or give no arguments at all, if you’re using a reasonably modern Python version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is not with the constructor of `BattleStartEvent`. It takes 2 arguments (aside from self), and that's what you are passing to it.

Your problem is then with the line inside said constructor:

```
super(BattleEvent, self).__init__(battle, buffable)
```

Doing `super(BattleEvent, self)` actually returns the class `BuffEvent` which takes one argument and as you can see you are passing 2 to it.

---

To fix this, either:

1. Fix your [`super()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#super) calls to use the actual class itself, not the parent (in all classes):

   ```
   class BattleStartEvent(BattleEvent):
       def __init__(self, battle, buffable):
           super(BattleStartEvent, self).__init__(battle, buffable)
   ```
2. In Python 3: Call with "empty" super: `super().__init__(battle, buffable)`
3. I am guessing that this code is just for a reproducible example, but if your `__init__` actually does nothing but call `super`, you can omit its implementation and the parent's `__init__` will be called by default.

---

For more useful information about `super`, see [Python’s super() considered super!](https://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/) by Raymond Hettinger.